# JS: how to read object array with dynamic properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays

backend server returns a sessions object with an array embedded, when I log it in the console, I get this:

```
Object {sessions: Array[3]}
    sessions: Array[3]
        0: Object
            data: Object
            id: "22"
            __proto__: Object
        1: Object
            data: Object
            id: "23"
            __proto__: Object
        2: Object
            data: Object
            id: "48"
            __proto__: Object
        length: 3
        __proto__: Array[0]
    __proto__: Object
```

so, there is an extra layer of objects with dynamic property names 0,1,2...

but I need to fill in a pure array of objects, like this:
[{id: "22", data: Object}, {id: "23", data: Object}, {id: "48", data: Object}]

so, I would refer to it like sessions[0].id... sessions[1].data... etc..

how should I reformat sessions to make it work as I wish?

Comment: `var sessions = answer_from_server.sessions;`?

Comment: *"there is an extra layer of objects with dynamic property names 0,1,2..."* `sessions` **is** an array. Arrays are objects too.

Answer (score 0):

> sessions[0].id... sessions[1].data

Yes, exactly as you said. Just add the returned object (whatever name you gave it - I'll call it returnedObject below)

```
console.log(returnedObject.sessions[0].id);
```

Or to get all sessions

```
console.log(returnedObject.sessions);
```

Or in a variable

```
var sessions = returnedObject.sessions;
```

Or all ids

```
var sessions = returnedObject.sessions;
sessions.forEach(session => {
    console.log(session.id);
});
```